# Local max/min of this

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$$f(x,y)=(x-y)^n$$ where $n \geq 1$ 
using this limitation $ x^2 + y^2 -1 =0$
I tried to find the derivatives 
$$
\begin{cases}
f_x = 2λx + n(x-y)^{n-1}=0 \\
f_y = 2λy - n(x-y)^{n-1}=0\\
f_λ = x^2 + y^2 -1 =0
 \end{cases}
$$

I get $x=y \quad λ=0 \quad with \quad x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$

However I have been told that this is wrong.And then 3x3 matrix becomes complex.But suggested (0,0,?) solution doesnt make sense as $f_l$ cant be zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1)$ Hint: $$ (x+(-y))^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k} x^{n-k}(-y)^k$$

$(2)$ $$x^2+y^2 = 1 \Rightarrow x = \sqrt{1-y^2} \Rightarrow (x-y)^n = (\sqrt{1-y^2}-y)^n.$$ $$\text{Now find the zeros of} \ \ g(x)=\sqrt{1-y^2}-y.$$ 
$$\text{Verify that your zero is the point $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$}. $$

$\textbf{Comment}$: And this makes sense because any zero of $f(x,y)=(x-y)^n$ is when $x=y$ and if we are limited to points on the boundary of the unit circle, the only time this happens is at the angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Now we understand this a bit better and it should follow that the max of $f(x,y)$ with this limitation is $1$ and the min is $-1$.

Comment: i have to solve without that

Comment: I have a limitation (dont know how it is called) $x^2 + y^2 -1=0$ I know the theory but at this example seems difficult for me to apply it.

Comment: yep but seems hard to solve the system

Comment: it makes sense and helps to verify. But what I was looking was Lagrange  , Lagarde method.Maybe it isnt possible ?

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with problem then. using lagrange multipliers I can find x=y and $x=\sqrt{2}/2$  but then I cant find λ. For λ=0 I get Det =0 meaning no solution

Answer (score 0):

Since the point $p=\{x,y\}$ is on unit circle, when $n$ is even the $\min$ is 0 and the $\max$ is 1, when $n$ is odd the $\min$ is $-1$ and the $\max$ is 1.